# Are python packets sent over sockets clear text?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, encoding, packet-sniffers

The title pretty much describes the question: if I send a packet containing, I don't know, some text inside it, from a python program to an other, if there's a hacker sniffing packets on the network, would they be able to see the content of the packet?

Comment: Generally yes, although some networks [encrypt everything](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/network-encryption) by policy. Windows offers this as a built-in feature and it's regularly enabled on big corporate domains.

Comment: Yes, they will be able to see exactly what you send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a [plain TCP or UDP socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) then the data you write into this socket are transferred in clear on the wire and can be sniffed unless the OS employs  encryption at the network layer or lower layers, i.e. VPN technologies like IPSec, OpenVPN or similar.

If instead you are using an [SSL wrapped socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) then the data will be encrypted inside the application and thus protected against sniffing provided that the SSL socket was created with secure settings (strong ciphers, proper certificate validation).

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna look this SSL wrapped socket thing up ^^.